# How to find window/iframe from Chrome DevTools

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape using Selenium, Python and Beautiful Soup. I am scraping [this](https://dmarket.com/csgo-skins/product-card/ak-47-redline/field-tested) page, but I want to scrape information off the pop-up window that appears when you click on the 'i' (information) icons in the corner of each product. My code is as follows:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import selenium
import math 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import chromedriver_binary
import re 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

r = requests.get('https://dmarket.com/csgo-skins/product-card/ak-47-redline/field-tested')
driver.get('https://dmarket.com/csgo-skins/product-card/ak-47-redline/field-tested')
html_getter = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = html_getter.findAll(attrs={"class":"c-asset__priceNumber"})
dataskin = html_getter.findAll(attrs={"class" : "c-asset__exterior"})
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("onesignal-slidedown-cancel-button").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-dialogHeader__close").click()
time.sleep(30)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-asset__action--info").click()
time.sleep(30)
price_element =  driver.switch_to.active_element
print("<<<<<TEXT>>>>>")
print(price_element.text)
print("<<<<<END>>>>>")
driver.close()
```

However, when I run this, the only text that prints are "close." If you inspect the information page pop-up, it should print out the price, data from the chart, etc. How can I get it to print this info? Specifically, I want the amount sold on the most recent day and the price listed on the chart on the most recent day (both seem to be accessible in Chrome DevTools). I don't think I'm looking at the wrong frame, as I switch to the active frame, so I'm not sure how to fix this!

Comment: At which line are you stuck? What error do you see?

Comment: currently, the only thing that price_element.text prints is "close" while I want it to print the price and volume as well. I just don't understand why these aren't printing. No actual error is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out!

Comment: @arundeepchohan it's actually still not printing anything. I'm still getting no text. I'm using driver.get_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='itemsDetails']/div[1]/div[2]/asset-card-price[1]/div/div/span/dm-currency-icon") and then I've tried .text and .get_attribute("innerHTML")